# How to repeatedly stack same row with certain amount of times

Tags: r, for-loop

this question is related to the post below, however, this is the more general from.

[How to split the data by time more efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471190/how-to-split-the-data-by-time-more-efficiently)

I have data, which repeatedly observed `ID` 1. The `value` is changing through time. `interval` is time interval when observation start and observation stop.

```
ID<-rep(1,4)
start<-c(0, 1, 4, 5)
stop<-c(1, 4, 5, 7)
sex<-c("M","M","M","M")
value<-c(10.5,20,13,19)
test<-data.frame(ID,start,stop,sex,value)
test<-test%>%mutate(rep=stop-start)

  ID start stop sex value interval
1  1     0    1   M  10.5        1
2  1     1    4   M  20.0        3
3  1     4    5   M  13.0        1
4  1     5    7   M  19.0        2
```

I want to duplicate the row and stack it repeatedly. In duplicating, I want (`interval`-1) copies of row. So,

```
  ID start stop sex value interval
1  1     0    1   M  10.5        1
2  1     1    4   M  20.0        3
2  1     1    4   M  20.0        3
2  1     1    4   M  20.0        3
3  1     4    5   M  13.0        1
4  1     5    7   M  19.0        2
4  1     5    7   M  19.0        2
```

second column of test duplicated two times(which is 3-1) and stacked.

I tried `for` loop, but it was very complicated. Is there a way to do it with `for` loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::uncount`

```
tidyr::uncount(test, rep, .remove = FALSE)

#    ID start stop sex value rep
#1    1     0    1   M  10.5   1
#2    1     1    4   M  20.0   3
#2.1  1     1    4   M  20.0   3
#2.2  1     1    4   M  20.0   3
#3    1     4    5   M  13.0   1
#4    1     5    7   M  19.0   2
#4.1  1     5    7   M  19.0   2
```

Or in base R, we can use `rep`

```
test[rep(1:nrow(test), test$rep), ]
```